# In UITableViewCell, UIImageView content repeats after some cells using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, afnetworking, restkit

The content is distinct on all the cells on the first page but as we scroll down, only the `UIImageView` is **repeated** though the `UILabel`s are **distinct**.

I am using `[UIImageView setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url]` from `AFNetworking` which was included in the `RestKit`. Heres the implementation

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RClubTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RClubTableViewCell"];
    RClubObject * club = _clubs[indexPath.row];
    [cell.clubImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:club.clubImageURL]];
    cell.nameLabel.text = club.clubName;
    return cell;
}
```

Seems like `iOS` is somehow using the previously created cells. Would like to have completely fresh cells while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` with a non-nil placeholder image to have the old image removed from the image view.

Comment: It is still repeating the images :-(

Comment: Log the url you use for each one, check the placeholder image (do you ever see it)

Comment: Ya, I see the placeholder image when the actual image is not yet loaded. 
As well all the URLs in `NSLog` are different.

Comment: iOS is reusing cells, you ask it to by dequeuing, init new cells if you want to. If you see the placeholder and the dupe images then your URLs are wrong or there is a bug in the AFN code...

Comment: Finally, it has worked for me, though I do not know how. And such things have happened before with me on iOS :-( . I created another `UIImageView` and discarded the previous one. It is exactly the same as the older one. Actually it si the Default UIImageView provided by Xcode with `Clip SubViews` and `Aspect Fill` . Then it just worked :-( . I tried cleaning the Code, even delete the `DerivedData` folder. But that did not work :-/ . If you can enlighten in this regard, it would be very helpful 1

Comment: Are you saying it's working with the stock image view of the cell but not a custom added subview? Does a club ever not have an image URL? You'd need to do some debugging and look for a pattern of when the dupe images are seen...

Comment: I can tell you that. The number is equal to the number of cells that the screen can hold + 1. Basically, the first set of cells are completely distinct, but as one cell is destroyed and another one created, it fetches the old data.

Comment: Yeah, some of the URLs are broken, but with adding this new `UIImageView` handeled broken URL's too!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed reallocation in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
Your code should be something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RClubTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RClubTableViewCell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[RClubTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    RClubObject * club = _clubs[indexPath.row];
    [cell.clubImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:club.clubImageURL]];
    cell.nameLabel.text = club.clubName;
    return cell;
}
```

**Update :**

Okay. I just had the same issue. Here what my search over google tells me : Since you are downloading the image in async and also scrolling, it gets downloaded and attached to other cells which are currently visible

**Solution:**

1. add tag to each imageView using indexpath.row
2. Use function `setImageWithURL: placeholderImage:success:`
3. In success block reload the cell using the tag value.

Though I haven't tested this I feel this should work. PS : Let me know if this works I also would have to do the same then :)

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work :-(  .  It never goes into that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS is reusing the previously created cells. That is what this line of code does, so that the app does not have to spend the time creating a new cell from scratch:

```
RClubTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RClubTableViewCell"];
```

Clear the image from the recycled cell before adding the new image for this cell:

```
cell.clubImageView.image = nil;
[cell.clubImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:club.clubImageURL]];
cell.nameLabel.text = club.clubName;
return cell;
```

Alternatively, you could create a new cell from scratch instead of dequeuing one.